# How to print on browser using POS printer

Tags: php

I want to print some simple text to a POS printer (many different models) from a browser. There might be different models but the sure thing is that the printer will be connected into a windows computer and have its drivers installed. The printer might be connected via usb. So, I want the user of the Windows computer to be able to press a button (one click) in my web application and print to the specific POS printers. The web app is written in php and uses jquery. So what I am asking, is how is this possible, and which is the easiest and best way to do that. Should I use javascript or what else? Is there a library? Will I face compatibility issues, if there are multiple pos printer models?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact setup [this pecl extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php) may be what you need.

You would need to share the printers on each of the machines with a common share name and when you go to attach to the printer you can use
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to build the unc to get to the printer.

The other option is if all of the printers speak the same page definition language like postscript then you can author the document with a library like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ps.php) dump it to a temp file and send it to the printer with an system lpr call